# std::istream without command line?

Tags: c++, iostream, getline

Basically I  have a thread reading from c++ std::istream using

```
istream& getline ( istream& is, string& str );
```

And when I bind the istream with `cin`, then it works fine when I type the input from standard command line as the input.

But I am wondering is there a way that I can make the read thread getline get the string without
using the actual command line ?

Basically I want to achieve this:

By just calling a function `WriteToIStream` with parameter `str` (instead of type str in command line) and the read thread getilne() can get the `str`.

```
void WriteToIStream(string& str)
{
//...
}
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Why use the global `cin` for this -- you could just make a new stream that's only used to communicate with the thread.

Comment: "get the string without using the actual command line" from where do you want to get the string then?

Comment: @KerrekSB: can u please give me a simple example as I haven't really written a new stream, only used those c++ iostream fstream etc. Also could boost::iostream help in this case ?

Comment: A `std::stringstream` should do the job.

Comment: @KerrekSB: so instead of using cin, I used a shared std::stringstream?

Comment: @ybungalobill: I don't have to use the cin, so yea I think I can get a string without command line. Read KerrekSB's comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cin` is only *one* instance of an input stream, bound to the standard input. For your case, you can use an [`istringstream`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istringstream/) (or more generally a `stringstream`) which is an input stream to read from a string:

```
std::istringstream istr("foobar");
getline(istr, some_string_variable);
```

This requires the standard header `<sstream>`.

Comment: getline default delim is '\n', so presume each time I need the getline need read sth from the shared istr, I just need to do istr<<"New String to be read from read thread\n" ?

Comment: @Gob00st No, you don’t need this since of course reading will stop at the end of the stream/string, no newline needed. This is **the same** as for any other stream. `istringstream` is *not* a special case.

Comment: I have tried this but when I use getline with istringstream in my read thread, it returns immediately instead of waiting for input like getline would do with cin. Could you explain why ?

Comment: @Gob00st The reason is that `cin.eof()` is `false` until the user *ends* the input to a program (usually by pressing Ctrl+D on the keyboard). An `istringstream`, on the other hand, is delimited by its content; once all of its content has been read, it’s done (and hence `eof() == true`).